# JSON POST Method in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to make a phpmyadmin database of product name, price and a short description. I have made a separate class  for JSON and the request is tranfered from another file which the source file an android activity. But After entering the values in the textview, the progress dialog box appears and then the activity force closes. In the logcat i can see the values that i have entered in the textview are available to the JSONParser.java class. Here is the JSONParser.java file.

Just for debugging purpose i am printing the json string in the logcat. But it shows that the JSON string is br / (with two angular brackets at the start and end) which shows it is the newline tag and clearly this can't be parsed to a JSON string which i think is the cause for force close. Thanks in advance. I'm stuck on this for the past two days.

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser
{
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser()
{

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params)
{

    // Making HTTP request
    try
    {
        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST")
        {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "is.toString() = " + is.toString());
            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "params.size = " + params.size());
            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "params.get(0) = " + params.get(0));
            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "params.get(1) = " + params.get(1));
            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "params.get(2) = " + params.get(2));
        }
        else if (method == "GET")
        {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

            Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "sb string append = " + sb.toString());
        }
        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();

        Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "json string = " + json);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "Exception e");
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.i("JSONPArser.java", "JSONException e");
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
    }
}
```

And here is the NewProductActivity.java file. It is the source file the android activity.

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity
{

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.199.80/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        Log.i("NewProductActivity.java", "name = " + name);
        Log.i("NewProductActivity.java", "price = " + price);
        Log.i("NewProductActivity.java", "description = " + description);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        //Log.i("NewProductActivity.java", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try
        {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1)
            {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                // failed to create product
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    }
}
```

And here's is the respective layout file for it. 
addproduct.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Name Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:text="Product Name"
    android:textSize="17dip" />

<!-- Input Name -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<!-- Price Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:text="Price"
    android:textSize="17dip" />

<!-- Input Price -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<!-- Description Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="17dip" />

<!-- Input description -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:lines="4" />

<!-- Button Create Product -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCreateProduct"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Product" />
```

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: logcat please and dont post your entire project just relevant portion of it

Comment: @SimplePlan logcat only shows that the string "<br />" can't be parsed to json type.

Comment: You need to use `.equals()` to compare strings

     `if (method.equals("POST"))`

Comment: @Raghunandan i value your suggestion but i have have put some log.i messages in the POST block they are getting executed. That means that the POST block code was executed till the end and the == sign didn't created a problem.

Comment: @user3340622 use .equals and similarly for get and then try. a simple search on google will give you the answer

Comment: @Raghunandan same error of br tag

05-24 14:42:04.999: E/JSON Parser(578): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @AkshaySoam the response does not look like a valid json. Check on the server side

Comment: @Raghunandan i'm not very efficient at networking. You mean there's a problem creating the database?

Comment: @AkshaySoam i don't work on the server side. So i cannot comment on that. But your response is not a valid json. pls check that

Comment: input given was meaningful and same is accessible to both the java files